# The value 'XX/YY/ZZZZ" is not valid for DateTime variable

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

On my webpage I have input where I keep current date:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreationDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'/'M'/'yyyy"), type = "datetime" })
```

which renders into:

```
<input value="31/3/2014" class="form-control datepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field CreationDate must be a date." data-val-required="Data jest wymagana" id="CreationDate" name="CreationDate" type="datetime">
```

As You can see the default data is `31/3/2014`

But when I'm trying to send it to my method using Ajax I got error from `ModelState`:

```
The value "31/3/2014" is not valid for CreationDate.
```

and this is what is in model:

```
+       CreationDate    {0001-01-01 00:00:00}   System.DateTime
```

To this input box is also set `bootstrap datepicker`:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "dd/MM/yyyy",
        language: "pl",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
```

which returns data like:

```
"31/Marzec/2014"
```

and with data above the `ModelState.Valid=true`

but there is need that input box default data should be valid. User should use Datepicker only when he needs to change to data other that current date.

How should I modify my code? I tryied messing with Formats in `toString()` with no effects.

Here my Model:

```
public class CreateDeviceInstance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Data jest wymagana")]
    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProjectId { get; set; }
    public bool Issue { get; set; }
    public string IssueDetails { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StorageId { get; set; }
    public bool MeAsUser { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `"dd'/'M'/'yyyy"` looks a little dubious to me. Are those single quotes correct?

Comment: @RajaDani: That wouldn't work, as `m` is minutes, not months.

Comment: @Cerbrus single quotes are escape mark for slashes. Without them the date string is as follows `31-03-2014`

Comment: dd/MM/yyyy will not work. use MM/dd/yyyy.it will work

Comment: @Jon Skeet, plz try this "dd/MM/yyyy".

Comment: @RajaDani: Well I can't try anything - we don't have enough information to reproduce the problem, just snippets. But yes, MM is the right format for 2-digit months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you 're using `"dd'/'M'/'yyyy"` format initially,

```
 (DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'/'M'/'yyyy"))
```

and  `"dd/MM/yyyy"` format later,

```
 format: "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

this is not good.
Use the same format (I suggest `"dd/MM/yyyy"`) in both cases.

Comment: Checked it. After changes is stil not valid because `CreationDate` from model = +  CreationDate {0001-01-01 00:00:00} System.DateTime

Comment: This line is not in the code posted in the question

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited question as fast as I realized I didn't pasted  that

Comment: As an aside, 0001-01-01 is the default value for a non nullable DateTime in C# - you could try making it nullable if you want the date picker to start on today's date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class CreateDeviceInstance 
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Data jest wymagana")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProjectId { get; set; }
    public bool Issue { get; set; }
    public string IssueDetails { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StorageId { get; set; }
    public bool MeAsUser { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

"31/Marzec/2014"  format : "dd/MM/yyyy"; do not use capital letters for specifying a month. The date format in bootstrap datepicker format : "dd/mm/yyyy" your result will change 31/03/2014